# Gremlin: Add an edge and drop an edge in single gremlin query

Tags: datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph

how to add an edge and dropping an edge to same vertex type in single gremlin query.

say we have two types of vertex types A --is--> B now i have vertex which is connected to some other vertex of B.

I want to update the A's vertex to some other vertex of B.

currently, i am dropping the current B vertex and then adding the new vertex .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in one traversal using a `sideEffect()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').as('m').
......1>   outE('knows').
......2>   filter(inV().has('person','name','vadas')).
......3>   sideEffect(drop()).
......4>   V().has('person','name','peter').
......5>   addE('knows').from('m')
==>e[13][1-knows->6]
```

At line 1 we basically identify the edge we want to get rid of (i.e. a "knows" edge from "marko" to "vadas") and we `drop()` that on line 3. At line 4 we lookup the vertex to whom we wish to connect "marko" to now and then add the edge at line 5.

Comment: Hey @Stephen, Any idea how can this be done in gremlin-scala. sideeffect is not working as expected in gremlin-scala

Comment: i am not able to use sideEffect as expected.g.V(businessVertex).as("a").outE()
        .and(_.label.is(EdgeLabels.IS_LABEL),
          _.inV().hasLabel(VertexLabels.TRIPTYPE_LABEL)).sideEffect(_=>__.drop()).iterate().  .. it not working its erroring out

Comment: [InvalidQueryException: Could not read the traversal from the request sent. Cause: Could not locate method: DefaultGraphTraversal.sideEffect([{}])]

Comment: why do you have `sideEffect()` being called that way (i.e. with what i think is a lambda)? should just be as i have it `sideEffect(_.drop())`

Comment: It does not work without it. It throws compilation issues.

Comment: I think you might need to raise an issue with gremlin-scala then maybe - https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/issues - that syntax works in all versions of Gremlin - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#sideEffect-org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal-

Comment: It should be `__.drop()`, not just `_.drop()`.

Comment: i thought gremlin-scala repurposed the double underscore for just single underscore. guess i could be wrong about that

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, could you please explain why we need a double score in gremlin scala. in DSE Studio we use double underscore.

Comment: Oh, I thought you guys just had a copy/paste typo. Now I actually looked at the examples on https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala and they use `_` as well as `__`, but I guess `_` is the right choice for scala. Sorry for the confusion.